# MySQL query for unique user and minimum score value

Tags: php, mysql

I need a SQL query for getting the lowest value of score for unique users. I need something similar to a golf leaderboard, where the lowest score needs to be on top, but there are multiple entries for a given user.

This is what I'm starting with:

```
<?php
    $order_by['score'] = 'asc';
    $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT(`username`), `id`, `score`, `type`, `created` FROM `scores` WHERE `username` != "" ';
    $sql .= 'GROUP BY `username` ';

    if(is_array($order_by)){
    $sql .= 'ORDER BY ';
    foreach($order_by as $field => $ascDesc){
    $order_by_array[] = '`'.$field.'`' . ' ' . strtoupper($ascDesc);
    }

    $sql .= implode(', ', $order_by_array);
    }
    $results = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error($con));
?>
```

This is coming back with unique usernames, but not their lowest score, it just grabs the first score it finds. How can I get it to return the lowest score?

---

Thanks RiaD! This is ultimately what worked for me:

```
SELECT `username`, `id`, MIN(`score`) as mn, `type`, `created` FROM `scores` WHERE `username` != "" GROUP BY `username` ORDER BY `mn` ASC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT username, MIN(score) as mn FROM scores GROUP BY username ORDER BY mn
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select username, MIN(score) as minscore from  scores where ... GROUP BY username
```